# The word "Unordered"

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

A set is an unordered collection of distinct objects.

What is the meaning of the word "unordered"?

Is it $$A=\{1,2,3,4,5,-1\}$$

$$B=\{-1,1,2,3,4,5\}$$

so $A=B$. That is the order does not matter?

Comment: Note that you need back-slashes to make curly braces display correctly in tex.

Comment: Yes, a set is determined by what's in it. The order in which you happen to write them down or think of them does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the order of the elements in a set (as they are listed) does not matter. A set is simply a *collection* of elements. If you had a basket of fruits, it doesn't matter which way you number the fruits; they are all in the basket! For example, the sets $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{2, 1, 3\}$ are equal, since their elements are the same.

On the other hand, an example of something that is ordered is a **tuple**: an ordered list of things. For example, the tuple $(1, 2, 3)$ is not the equal to the tuple $(2, 1, 3)$, since their first and second entries are different.